# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl incompatible with com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, websphere, cdi, classcastexception

I am using Websphere liberty profile to deploy my rest api. I see below error message when I try to test my api. I have no clue where this jboss classes are coming form. I literally don't find any files related to JBOSS.
 Can anyone please explain where these Jboss errors are coming from

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [REST Service] in application [gmc]: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl incompatible with com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:330)
    at [internal classes]



[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4898)
        at [internal classes]
    Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:399)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl incompatible with com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:180)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:95)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:76)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:332)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:330)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have CDI-1.2 configured in server.xml. Liberty uses the CDI RI which is weld and comes in a jboss package which is where the classes come from. You have Jersey in your app which is doing something weird, but what I don't know without more info on versions.

Comment: JBoss is just a software company like Apache, IBM, Sun/Oracle, etc. Among others, they are creators of Weld, a CDI implementation which happens to be used by WebSphere. It's not the JBoss AS orso as you seemed to think. You're also not wondering what exactly those Sun classes are doing there in your IBM server, right? That's not their GlassFish server, but just their JAX-RS implementation which happens to be used by WebSphere.

Comment: WebSphere does not use Jersey as it's JAX-RS implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please enable the following feature in your `server.xml` in place of its older version and see the result?

`<feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>`

Comment: Not sure how this would help given Jersey is being used and not the Libery JAX-RS implementations.

Comment: Could you share `common,  minimal, verifiable` code?